# PyWinAuto: Click() fails until mouse is physically clicked

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to get PyWinAuto to click a button as soon as it's enabled. Here's what I currently have:

```
while running:
        try:
            app = pywinauto.Application().connect(title='Microsoft Outlook', class_name="#32770")['Microsoft Outlook']
            app.Allow.Wait('ready', retry_interval=0.1)
            app.Allow.Click()
            print('Clicked')


        except (pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError, pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pass
```

This works just fine if I start it running after the button is active, clicking and printing 'Clicked' as expected. If I run it before the button is active, it waits for it as expected and then seems to *try* and click it - Printing 'clicked' repeatedly until I click either mouse button or press enter. If I take the click() out and get it to just return app.Allow then the result is as expected regardless of when I load the script, so it does seem to be click() that's the hangup.

The behaviour is the same regardless of where I click or which window I have active - It'll work if I click anywhere or anything, but it won't do anything at all until I do... Which defeats the object of the automation, really!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to run the script as Administrator if you use `.connect(...)`. I've already added warning about that and error in the `.click()` method when target process has higher privileges. See [pull request #499](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/499). It will be included into coming pywinauto==0.6.5.

There is one more method: `.click_input()` moves mouse cursor and performs real click. While `.click()` just sends `WM_CLICK` window message (might be useful for minimized or non-active window).

P.S. By the way, for Outlook I'd recommend using `Application(backend="uia")` and you'll have no Win32 API specific problems. See [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) about backends difference.

Comment: Cheers Vasily but I'm not much further forward.

I've run the script as administrator and I'm seeing the same symptoms, and I'm deliberately using the w32 backend - Although the prompt is labelled 'Microsoft Outlook' it's not contained within Outlook itself and it is a legacy prompt that I'm trying to click away.

click_input() doesn't work on minimized or non-active windows at all does it? That was my main reason for using the click() method instead.

Comment: Yes, click_input() requires active window. The root cause might be in the WM_CLICK message handler on the app side. As a workaround you may try .send_chars(“{ENTER}”) before .click().

Comment: The difference for send_chars/type_keys is the same as for click/click_input.

Comment: Tried the send_chars workaround, still no dice - Even with the {ENTER} input it was sticking until I clicked before advancing. Weird. Thanks for the idea though, I might see if I can factor that in to a different approach. That's a job for tomorrow anyway.

Comment: I mean not a WM_LBUTTONDOWN/WM_CLICK handler itself but the code which enables this handler. It may run after some trigger. Can it be the app issue/bug?

Comment: It's entirely possible that it's a bug at the app's end. I have now found a workaround, ish. Sending `click_input()` after the `click()` causes it to work as expected, with the minor side effect of the random click on whichever window the user happens to have open. It's preferable to not having it work at all for my use-case at least.

I tried to circumvent the random click hangup by hooking `click_input()` using `mouse` but that just got me back to square one. Ah well.

Comment: Maybe `app.wait_cpu_usage_lower()` may help also. It waits while app related CPU usage becomes below threshold. If the dialog makes lazy initialization with late binding of click handlers, CPU usage is better indication of initialization being done. Just one more trick. :)

Comment: Any success on that?

Comment: Haven't been able to test yet - I'll get back to you when I've got some more time to poke at the issue!